# Dividing units with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having troubles learning how to divide units that have negative exponents.

I have tried multiple times and I am not sure if i am doing it right.

This is the question:

$\dfrac{2\pi(12x^{-2})}{\pi(2x^{-3})}$

Comment: I got an answer of 12x, did anyone else get that?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Here is a link that explains many of the rules and where they come from http://mathontrack.comze.com/exponentials2.html. It's not my website, honest it's not :p

Answer (score 1):

One of the "laws" of exponents will help you here. In particular,

$$\frac{x^m}{x^n}=x^{m-n}=\frac{1}{x^{n-m}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $x^{-a}$ means $1/x^a$.  So
$$\frac{2\pi(12x^{-2})}{\pi2x^{-3}}=\frac{2\pi(12/x^2)}{\pi(2/x^3)}=\cdots\,?$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way. An exponent is repeated use of multiplication.

For example, $ x^3 = x(x)(x) $.

Division is the inverse of multiplication. It "undoes" the process of multiplying. If multiplying adds to the exponent, then division has to subtract.

For example $$ \frac{x^3}{x} = \frac{x(x)(x)}{x} = x(x) = x^{3 - 1} = x^2 $$.

And in general, $$ \frac{x^n}{x^m} = x^{n - m} $$.

One further example to drive this home,

$$ \frac{x^{-5}}{x^{-2}} = x^{(-5)-(-2)} = x^{-5+2} = x^{-3} $$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ \frac{1}{x^{-1}}=x $$
Here are the steps
$$
\frac{2\pi 12x^{-2}}{2\pi x^{-3}}=\frac{12x^{-2}}{x^{-3}}=\frac{12}{x^{-1}}=12x
$$